# Definition of Clique width of graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

The clique width of graph $G$ is defined as minimum number of labels required to construct $G$ by using [four operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-width). 
I would like to know why the name clique width is given to this definition. How it is related to clique definition.

Comment: It's reasonable to name it clique-width as clique-width of clique is bounded, unlike other width parameters.

Comment: The name may not be the best choice; some name had to be chosen though. There is a small commentary about this in [Algorithmic uses of the Feferman–Vaught Theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2003.11.002) by Makowsky. The name does seem better than $k$-NLC-graphs, though ;)

Comment: I think the idea of the name cliquewidth is that it essentially extends tree-width to a "tree of cliques".